# HDMI passthrough overlay from Wii U to PC

Tags: display, hdmi, desktop-computer, overlay, wii-u

I recently purchased a Wii U, and I really enjoy it, but I seem to have run into a usability problem. I only have one monitor, and it is not possible for me to purchase a second one. Therefore, I must plug the Wii U into the same monitor as my PC, not allowing me to use both at the same time. Is there any way for me to overlay the Wii U output on top of the PC output? Thanks again!

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot connect 2 different HDMI sources to a single HDMI input and have 1 overlay the other - The best option, for your scenario, would be to get an HDMI switch box and connect both devices to it. Then, just swap channels on the box when you want to use either device. Your other option would be to use another available input port on your TV (if you have that available to you)

Answer (score 0):

They do make HDMI capture cards allowing you to display an HDMI input on your computer, but they are far too laggy for gameplay.  Plus, they are quite pricey.  You might as well buy a second monitor for the price.

Another option is that some monitors support picture-in-picture.  Yours probably doesn't, but if space is an issue, you might find a new monitor that does.

The cheapest option is to buy an HDMI switcher.  These can be obtained for $15 or so, and will allow you to share one HDMI input with multiple devices by switching back and forth, much like unplugging a cable and plugging in the next.  This won't enable you to use both devices on the same monitor simultaneously.